# How to get the relevant entry from Tkinter when creating widgets from functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having an issue with the below block of code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Recipe Input Form")

    def create_input_field(self, label_text):
        # Create a label
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text=label_text)
        self.label.pack()

        # Create an entry widget for input
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.entry.pack()

        # Create a submit button
        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=lambda entry=self.entry, label_text=label_text: self.submit(entry, label_text))
        self.submit_button.pack()

    def submit(self, entry, label_text):
        # Get the input from the entry widget
        user_input = self.entry.get()

        # Do something with the input (for example, print it)
        print(f"You entered:{label_text}, user_input: {user_input}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)

    # recipe number field 
    recipe_number = app.create_input_field(label_text="Recipe number")
    other_pars = app.create_input_field(label_text="other_params")
    root.mainloop()
```

When clicking the first submit button, I am getting the output in the second entry field.

When I only enter something in the first entry `recipe_number` the function `submit` does not print the entered value when pressing the respective button:

`You entered:Recipe number, user_input:`

If I enter "test_other_params" into the second entry `other_params` and then click the respective submit button I get:

`You entered:Recipe number, user_input: test_other_params`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `submit` function you are getting the `self.entry`which was last set to the `other_pars` element you created in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. That is why you get nothing returned if the second field is empty or the value of the second one if it contains something for both inputs:

```py
# You set self.entry as recipe_number
recipe_number = app.create_input_field(label_text="Recipe number")
# but then you override it with other_pars
other_pars = app.create_input_field(label_text="other_params")
```

What you have to change is accessing the `entry` element you pass into the `submit` function:

```py
def submit(self, entry, label_text):
    # Get the input from the entry widget
    user_input = entry.get()  # get the entry you passed, not the self.entry

    # Do something with the input (for example, print it)
    print(f"You entered:{label_text}, user_input: {user_input}")
```

Since you do not need the `self` argument in this function you can delete it and give the function the `@staticmethod` decorator as well:

```py
@staticmethod
def submit(entry, label_text):
```

Comment: This was it. Removing the 'self' did it. Thanks a lot. I need to read up a bit more about the @staticdecorator

Answer (score 0):

> In the continuation of Mr.[`@Jan_B`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22326950/jan-b)'s answer Here are the changes I made:
>
> Inside the **`create_input_field`** method, I removed
> **`self.label`**, **`self.entry`**, and **`self.submit_button`** as class attributes because they don't need to be stored as instance
> variables. You can directly create and pack these widgets without
> saving references to them.
>
> In the submit method, I changed **`self.entry.get()`** to
> **`entry.get()`** because you want to get the value from the specific entry widget associated with the button that was clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Recipe Input Form")

    def create_input_field(self, label_text):
        # Create a label
        label = tk.Label(self.root, text=label_text)
        label.pack()

        # Create an entry widget for input
        entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        entry.pack()

        # Create a submit button
        submit_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=lambda entry=entry, label_text=label_text: self.submit(entry, label_text))
        submit_button.pack()

    def submit(self, entry, label_text):
        # Get the input from the entry widget
        user_input = entry.get()
        
        # Do something with the input (for example, print it)
        print(f"You entered: {label_text}, user_input: {user_input}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)

    # Create input fields
    recipe_number = app.create_input_field(label_text="Recipe number")
    other_params = app.create_input_field(label_text="other_params")
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

> When clicking the first submit button, I am getting the output in the
> second entry field.
>
> I entered some data in Recipe number and get the below output.
>
> You entered:Recipe number, user_input:
>
> If I enter "test_other_params" into the other_params entry box, and
> then click the submit button under Recipe number, I get the below: You
> entered:Recipe number, user_input: test_other_params

The problem can be fixed.

The reasoning why is that you created too many widgets. That is why I used one `Label`, `Entry` and `Button` widgets.

You need to do Updating `Label` by using `configure`.

I also add delete `Entry` widget when the button is pressed.

I moved the `app.create_input_field(label_text="other_params")`. So, when the button is pressed, it is need to update "other_params".

- Move The `Label`, `Entry` and `pack` widgets to `__init__` function.
- Move the `Button` widget to  `__init__` function.
- Add the `self.submit_button.configure` and `self.label.configure` in `create_input_field()` function.
- Move the app.create_input_field(label_text="other_params") to
  `sumbit()` function.
- Add `self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)` in `submit()` function.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Recipe Input Form")
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text='Recipe number')
        self.label.pack(side=tk.TOP) 
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
         
        self.entry.pack()
        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Submit")
        
    def create_input_field(self, label_text):
      # Create a submit button
        self.submit_button.configure(command=lambda entry=self.entry, label_text=label_text: self.submit(entry, label_text))        
         
        self.submit_button.pack()
        self.label.configure(text=label_text)
        

    def submit(self, entry, label_text):
         
        # Get the input from the entry widget
        #self.label.configure(text=label_text)
        app.create_input_field(label_text="other_params")
        #self.label.configure(text=label_text)
        user_input = self.entry.get()
        

        # Do something with the input (for example, print it)
        print(f"You entered:{label_text}, user_input: {user_input}")
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
         
         

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)

    # recipe number field
    app.create_input_field(label_text="Recipe number")
    #app.create_input_field(label_text="other_params")
```

Screenshot:

[image]